# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 DI: ServiceProvider not resolving type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the code below, `serviceProvider.GetService<DocumentDbConnection>()` is resolving to `null`:

```
public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    services.AddSingleton<DocumentDbConnection>(
        x => new DocumentDbConnection(uri, authKey));

    // service is null?
    var connection = serviceProvider.GetService<DocumentDbConnection>();

    services.AddTransient<IStopRepository, StopRepository>(
        x => new StopRepository(connection, databaseId, collectionId));
}
```

Why is this happening? The type is being registered before `GetService` is called so should it not resolve to the singleton?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are building the service provider *before* you register the `DocumentDbConnection`. You should register the services you need first. Then `BuildServiceProvider` will build a service provider with the services registered until then:

```
services.AddSingleton<DocumentDbConnection>(x => new DocumentDbConnection(uri, authKey));
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// code using serviceProvider
```